# ID select php/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have an select option like this :

```
    for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    {
        $body .= <<<EOT

    <form method="GET" action="page2.php">
    <select class="multiSelect" size="7" name="opt[]" id="{$i}">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    ...
    </select>
    </form>
EOT;
    }
```

In the second page page2.php

```
if (isset($_GET['opt']) && !empty($_GET['opt']))
    {

        foreach($_GET['opt'] as $opt)
            $html .= "You have choice the option $opt in the !!!! $i !!!! select <br />\n" ;

    }
```

I want to get the id ($i) of each select in the page2.php ? Can You help me please ? Thanks

Comment: What you have here is a loop creating 5 different forms.

Comment: I want to have 5 list with different ID, it's all about that. and after get different option that I select + the ID of the select. Help me please

Comment: Then put the `form` tag creation **outside** the loop. And loop only through the `select` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

I moved the form tag out of the loop, so that all selects are included in one form, I then assigned a unique name to each form.

```
$body .= '<form method="GET" action="page2.php">';

for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
{
    $body .= <<<EOT
        <select class="multiSelect" size="7" name="opt_$i[]" id="{$i}">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        ...
        </select>

EOT;
}
$body.= '</form>';
```

and on page2 you want to do something like this:
here I use 2 loops, the first one is looping through your selects (I'm assuming you always have 5 selects), I generate the name of each form with opt_$i (will be opt_1 ... opt_5)

With the second loop, I loop through all selected values that where selected in that select

```
$html = 'your choices:<br/>';
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    $sel = "opt_$i";    
    $html.= "in Select $i you selected:";
    foreach($_GET[$sel] as $opt){
        $html.= $opt;
    }
}
```

you def. want to make the output prettier, but that should be easy to do and just adds more code, making it harder to see the essential steps.

Comment: Part of the question is this: "I want to get the id ($i) of each select in the page2.php" --> this sounds to me like he wants all selects submitted, for that they need to be in one form and they need different name tags. Thats what I did. Maybe I misunderstood the intentiosn of the asker, but its hard to understand what he really wants to acheive.

Comment: Can you give me the code in http://jsfiddle.net please ? Thank you. It's  that I want but it's not work for me @cytofu

Comment: I have this error :  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

if for whatever reason you want to keep your 5 forms:
you could pass the id of the select as a get Param like this:

```
action="page2.php?selectId=$i"
```

and use `$_GET['selectId']` to retrieve it on page2

if that is also not what you want please explain more clearly WHAT you want?

Comment: it's not work... because the <form method="get action="page2.php"> is not in the loop (for) and it don't recognize the $i.. Can you give me more explanation please thank you

Comment: in your question it is in the loop.. which is as the commenters where pointing out creating several forms. I'm not sure why you want to get the ID. You could use the name of the select, like I pointed out in my other answer, if you only want to know which anmswer came from which select. Pls. let me know what you don't like about my other answer so I can adjust it, I think it is pretty much what you want.

Comment: So I have some soccer team like in CHampions league.. And I add some team in this groups... I want to get all this team with his group and I pass the number of the group in the ID of the select. You know

Comment: so whats wrong with getting the nr. from the name attribute?? I assume you use 1 select for one team? Otherwise what you want to get is propably the value of selected options.